# I want to add file uploader to existing content uploader via Dreamweaver - upload pdf to specific folder, url to pdf generated in database

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

So I've been following [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/first_dynamic_site_pt1.html) tutorial on creating an admin CMS for uploading content to a MySQL database via. Dreamweaver and it seems to be working fine no problems, ace. So I thought, "hmm surely it must be easy to do a similar one that allows me to upload a file to a specific directory and have the URL generated in the database" So I clone both the 'news' database and admin pages to be utilised for 'files' - adding a new field in the database called 'url' which is just text. I copy the method Wordpress uses, so each entry for example will be something like "../library/test.pdf" (goes back to root dir of site then to "library" section etc.). I manually added a test entry in the database and moved a file to the 'library' directory - and by using 'htmlentities' to encode the 'url' link for the text in the 'name' column of the CMS - it had no problem display the manually defined url automatically - So far so good?

Tried to see if there was a way to do what I wanted to do JUST through Dreamweaver but it didn't seem possible. So tried following [this](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/910953) (which pretty much describes EXACTLY what I want to do!!)... but the answer links to an about.com tutorial - which I read in the thread is shoddy clode - which explains why it doesn't bloody work! :'(

So, here's my code (well, what I've done after the first paragraph)... (excl. connector to dtabase)

**PHP**

```
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

 switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
 }
  return $theValue;
}
}



$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}



if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO library (name, `description`, url) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['description'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['url'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_tectanet, $tectanet);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $tectanet) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "manage_files.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
 }


?>
```

**HTML** the important "body" bit anyway

```
<body>
<h1>Add file</h1>
<p><a href="index.php">Admin Menu</a></p>
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"    name="form1" id="form1">
    <p>
      <strong>
    <label for="name">name</label> 
    :
    <br />
<input name="name" type="text" class="titleinput" id="name" maxlength="150" />
  </strong> </p>
  <p><strong>desc</strong>:<br />
 <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="file" name="url" id="url" />
  </p>
<p>
  <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Post" />
</p>
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
```

Much appreciated if someone can help! Though if not I'm sure I can figure this out in a couple of hours.. but it's been frustrating me for a day already just because I thought it'd be simple to do :P

Comment: Should add I'm using Dreamweaver CS5 - I want this done so I can add a file and have it auto generate on a library page on the website rather than uploading files to FTP and manually updating the page.

Answer (score 0):

You do upload the file, but you don't handle it.

Whenever a file is uploaded using a form, is is placed in the server's temporary directory. You'll have to move the file from the temporary directory to it's final location (chosen by  you), otherwise it will be deleted again after script execution.

I think you can better start with a simple form to upload the file and move it to a directory you want. If you've managed to get it working, then you can construct a final url, based on the directory the file is placed.

Start with following the [directions from php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). In your case, the save script would look something like this:

```
$target_directory = realpath('/path/to/http_root/files') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

$target_file = $target_directory . basename($_FILES['url']['name']);

if($_FILES['url']['error'] > 0) {
    echo 'An error occured while uploading your file... Check the error code ('. $_FILES['url']['error'] .') at <a href="http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php">http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php</a> to find out what went wrong.<br>';
} else {
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['url']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
        throw new Exception('Something went wrong while saving the uploaded file');
    }
    $target_directory_url = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/files/'; // url to the $target_directory
    $target_file_url = $target_directory_url . basename($_FILES['url']['name']);
    echo 'You can find your uploaded file at '. $target_file_url;
}
```

If I may advise you; only save the filename in the database. As you know in which directory it is stored, you don't need the full url or path in the database. And when you move the directory (and thus the url), you only have to alter the function that constructs the url for you, and don't have to do some complex update queries to replace the full paths in the database.

**EDIT** added a line of code to print out the relevant error code if something went wrong while uploading. It still throws an exception when the file cannot be moved for some reason.

Comment: Okay, following your method and it seems to work half the time - but sometimes gives me Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Something went wrong while saving the uploaded file' in (link to phpscript) Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in (link to phpscript) on line 8. Why would it do this?

Comment: check my edit, the error code should give you enough info to find out what went wrong (most probably something with `post_max_size`, `upload_max_filesize` or one of the other ini settings, as listed on the [php documentation](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)